# Mozilla undo "Always Block Notifications"

Tags: mozilla, web-notifications

Using the web notifications api Mozilla will ask user for permission. If I choose 'Always Block Notifications' there seems no way to undo that setting(?).

I've checked about:config, and dom.notifications.enabled is true.

But calling Notification.requestPermission() never shows the popup again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the menu at right-hand side of the Firefox toolbar, go to History -> Show All History. Find the site in question, right-click on it, and choose Forget About This Site from the context menu. This will clear all site data and site-related preferences including the notifications preferences, so you'll be able to get the notification prompt again.

Comment: Great! Would you mind accepting the answer as well, then? :)